# Как ускорить загрузку файлов с сервера?

Tags: delphi, http

Код сервера:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  Dirrectory: String;
begin
  if ARequestInfo.URI = '/' then
  begin
  ...
  end else
  begin
    Dirrectory := StringReplace(ARequestInfo.URI, '/', '\', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
    if FileExists(Dirrectory) then
    begin
      AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
      AResponseInfo.ContentType := AResponseInfo.HTTPServer.MIMETable.GetFileMIMEType(Dirrectory);
      AResponseInfo.ContentStream := TFileStream.Create(Dirrectory, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
    end else
    begin
      AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 404;
    end;
    AResponseInfo.WriteContent;
  end;
end;
```

При обращение клиента, страница грузится долго, то есть секунды 3-4.

Возможно ли ускорить этот код?

Comment: А размер файла какой?

Comment: @zed от 1 КБ до 1 МБ

Comment: Т.е. на ненагруженном сервере, у вас занимает 3 секунды загрузка файла размером в 1kB? Очень странно.

Comment: @zed Нет, 100 файлов от 1 КБ до 1 МБ, до полной загрузки сайта

Comment: А, ну так дисковые операции и тормозят.

Comment: @zed "дисковые операции" это процесс загрузки файла в поток?

Comment: Это процесс чтения файла с диска на сервере. Если не ошибаюсь, Indy из потока не загружает файл целиком в память, а считывает в буфер по 32k и отправляет этот буфер клиенту. Не думаю, что тут можно что-то ускорить, если вам нужно грузить разные файлы. Если же у вас всего 100 файлов, то имеет смысл загрузить их в память при старте сервера, а потом отдавать клиенту их из памяти, не обращаясь к диску.